# node.jsとexpressのexpress.staticについて

Tags: javascript, node.js

node.jsとexpressを用いたサーバ構築についてわからないことがあったので質問します。

質問内容は

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```

と

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){});
```

の記述順番によって意図しない結果が返ってくるというものです。

---

質問：
パターン１の位置にexpress.staticを記述し、[http://localhost:3000にアクセスすると](http://localhost:3000%E3%81%AB%E3%82%A2%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BB%E3%82%B9%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8)、index.htmlの内容が表示されるのはなぜでしょうか？
また、htmlのファイル名がindex.htmlの時にだけこの現象が起こるのですがなぜでしょうか？

想定している動き：
app.getではtestpage.html（存在しないhtml）を返すと記述しているので、localhost:3000にアクセスするとError: ENOENTとなるはずでは？

備考：
普段はパターン2の位置にexperss.staticを記述していました。2の位置にexpress.staticを記述しlocalhost:3000にアクセスするとError: ENOENTとなります(想定通り)

認識している点：

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

指定したディレクトリ以下の静的ファイルを公開する

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){});
```

引数で指定されたGETリクエストに対して処理を行う。今回の質問の場合指定したhtmlファイルを返す。

---

以下サンプルを示します。

ディレクトリ構成
app
 ├package.json
 ├app.js
 ├node_modules
 │　└express
 └public
　　└index.html

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

//パターン１
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/testpage.html');
});

//パターン2
//app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

http.listen(3000, function(){
 console.log('Web Server listening on *:3000');
});
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
    <title>testpage</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Test Page</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

基本的なことで恐縮ですが教えていただけるとありがたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`index.html`は`/`に対しての予約語・エイリアスとして定着している言わば方言で、ディレクトリのエントリポイント（最初にアクセスするべきファイル）を指します。`Apache`や`nginx`, `node-static`など、他のサーバーでも頻繁に利用されている設定です。

`express.static`の実態は[`serve-static`モジュール](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static#serve-files-with-vanilla-nodejs-http-server)です。第二引数で`/`の振る舞いを変更することが出来ます。

`express()`の`.use`,`.get`,`.post`などは、書いた順番に`url`が一致するかチェックを行いますが、コールバック関数の第三引数(e.g.`function(req,res,next){next()}`)を実行すると、一致している場合でも、次のコールバック関数に処理をそのまま渡すことが出来ます。

```bash
$ node app.js
# Web Server listening on *:3000

$ open http://localhost:3000/
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
```

```js
var express= require('express');
var app= express();
var http= require('http').Server(app);

app.use(function(req,res,next){
  console.log('1');
  next();
});
app.use('/',function(req,res,next){
  console.log('2');
  next();
});
app.get('/',function(req,res,next){
  console.log('3');
  next();
});

app.use(function(req,res,next){
  console.log('4');
  res.status(404).end('404 Notfound');
});

http.listen(3000,function(){
  console.log('Web Server listening on *:3000');
});
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。今回の質問の構成でパターン１の位置にexpress.staticを記述し,`/`にアクセスすると、app.getより先に`express.static`が解釈され、エントリポイント(index.html)にアクセスするということですね。
また、パターン2の位置に`express.static`を記述すると、先に`app.get`が解釈され、Error: ENOENTが返るということである、と理解しました。